# "Could not find module ‘Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse’ Error " while installing Haskelly extension dependencies using haskell stack

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm trying to install Haskelly extension for vs studio code by following the steps [here](https://github.com/haskelly-dev/Haskelly#installation).

```
    rajkumar@linux-2278:~> stack install intero QuickCheck stack-run
    stack-run-0.1.1.4: configure
    stack-run-0.1.1.4: build

    --  While building package stack-run-0.1.1.4 using:
        /home/rajkumar/.stack/setup-exe-cache/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-simple_mPHDZzAJ_2.4.0.1_ghc-8.6.5 --builddir=.stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1 build --ghc-options " -ddump-hi -ddump-to-file -fdiagnostics-color=always"
        Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
        Logs have been written to: /home/rajkumar/.stack/global-project/.stack-work/logs/stack-run-0.1.1.4.log

        Configuring stack-run-0.1.1.4...
        Preprocessing executable 'stack-run' for stack-run-0.1.1.4..
        Building executable 'stack-run' for stack-run-0.1.1.4..

        /tmp/stack30563/stack-run-0.1.1.4/unix/System/Console/Questioner.hs:4:14: warning:
            -XOverlappingInstances is deprecated: instead use per-instance pragmas OVERLAPPING/OVERLAPPABLE/OVERLAPS
        |
        4 | {-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances  #-}
        |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        [1 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner.Autocomplete ( unix/System/Console/Questioner/Autocomplete.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner/Autocomplete.o )
        [2 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner.Util ( unix/System/Console/Questioner/Util.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner/Util.o )
        [3 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner.ProgressIndicators ( unix/System/Console/Questioner/ProgressIndicators.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner/ProgressIndicators.o )
        [4 of 5] Compiling System.Console.Questioner ( unix/System/Console/Questioner.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/System/Console/Questioner.o )
        [5 of 5] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-2.4.0.1/build/stack-run/stack-run-tmp/Main.o )

        /tmp/stack30563/stack-run-0.1.1.4/src/Main.hs:18:1: error:
            Could not find module ‘Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse’
            Perhaps you meant
            Distribution.PackageDescription.Parsec (needs flag -package-key Cabal-2.4.0.1)
            Distribution.PackageDescription.Parsec (from Cabal-2.4.1.0)
            Distribution.PackageDescription.Check (needs flag -package-key Cabal-2.4.0.1)
            Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
        |
        18 | import           Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse
```

Below is the contents of `/home/rajkumar/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml` -

```
    packages: []
    resolver: lts-13.21
    allow-newer: true
    extra-deps:
    - conduit-1.2.13.1
    - conduit-extra-1.1.17
    - resourcet-1.1.11
    - streaming-commons-0.1.19
```

cabal version -

```
    $ cabal --version
    cabal-install version 2.4.1.0
    compiled using version 2.4.1.0 of the Cabal library
```

stack version -

```
    $ stack --version
    Version 1.9.3, Git revision 40cf7b37526b86d1676da82167ea8758a854953b (6211 commits) x86_64 hpack-0.31.1
```

Below are the OpenSuse OS details -

```
    rajkumar@linux-2278:~> lsb_release -a
    LSB Version:    core-2.0-noarch:core-3.2-noarch:core-4.0-noarch:core-2.0-x86_64:core-3.2-x86_64:core-4.0-x86_64:desktop-4.0-amd64:desktop-4.0-noarch:graphics-2.0-amd64:graphics-2.0-noarch:graphics-3.2-amd64:graphics-3.2-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch
    Distributor ID: openSUSE
    Description:    openSUSE Leap 15.0
    Release:        15.0
    Codename:       n/a
```

This also happens in Fedora 30 OS -

```
    $ lsb_release -a
    LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
    Distributor ID: Fedora
    Description:    Fedora release 30 (Thirty)
    Release:        30
    Codename:       Thirty
```

I don't know how to resolve this issue. Any idea would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You are running Cabal version 2.4 and package `Distribution.PackageDescription.Parse` was removed in Cabal 2.2. [See Cabal issue tracker](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/5025).

Consider using `Distribution.PackageDescription.Parsec` instead. [They are using that in obelisk project](https://github.com/obsidiansystems/obelisk/issues/106).

Comment: I'm not directly using cabal. The error is from `stack install intero QuickCheck stack-run`. Do you mean I have to downgrade my cabal version? If so, I can't because that is packaged with ghcup itself. Is there any workaround?

Comment: Not very familiar with stack and your project, but generally I'd recommend fixing the code you are compiling than downgrading its dependencies.

Comment: The error is not in my code at all. Please see here https://github.com/haskelly-dev/Haskelly#installation

Answer (score 0):

As per the doco for Haskelly, if you run into issues, refer to 
https://github.com/yamadapc/stack-run/issues/17#issuecomment-427545735

Essentially, modify your stack.yml, then run individually:

```
stack build
stack build intero
stack install QuickCheck
stack --stack-yaml ~/.stack/global-project/stack-cabal-1.24.yaml install stack-run
```